# Claims identity object getting purged after user is redirected to landing page with successful login

Tags: sitecore-client, multisite

I’m recently doing a POC for Multisite POC with same domain implementation using virtual folder concept.

However I ended up facing an issue such that when you user is successful Authenticated by OKTA and redirected to landing page. Post that user claims identity object is getting null and due to which customer personalisation and Sitecore session everything is getting purged.

I’m using Sitecore 10.2 instance and following Sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/configure-multiple-managed-websites.html

https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/sitecore-multi-sites-with-same-domain-but-different-sitecore-item-node/

Let me know if anything I’m missing here.